# Winform toolStrip Status Label shows nothing: is this a bug?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Have an instruction like this:

```
this.toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = 
      this.toolStripStatusLabel1.Text + "; OS=" +
      System.Environment.OSVersion.ToString();
```

If I concatenate OS with something that is more than 10 characters text is blank instead of being truncated. Is this a Bug ?

Answer (score 0):

- Check your font size
- Ensure that the autosize is set to true
- As suggested by Henk, check width of the label

Comment: autosize is true, in debug mode variable content is ok, width cannot be changed, but it expands to the whole window so no problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you pause your program (place a breakpoint right after this happening), what does it say the text is? Empty, or is it still the complete string?

Btw, you can use += instead of repeating the name of the label.Text after the =-sign.

Comment: and on that note use string.format() or a stringbuiler if you are changing string contents a lot (like in a loop)... string are immutable.

Comment: But there is no loop here, and an SB would be overkill.